# Must declare scalar variable datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me. Why is this code not working? Says `@FromDate` must declare scalar variable

```
Alter Procedure rpt_1
as
    declare @FromDate Datetime 
    declare @ToDate Datetime
    declare @LocId int
Begin
    select 
        cl.CashLocationName, 
        convert(date,fn.DocumentDate) DocumentDate, 
        u.UserName,
        sum(TotalPayment) TotalVanzare, sum(CashAmount) TotalCash, 
        sum(CardAmount) TotalCard, sum(TicketPaymentAmount) TotalTichete, 
        sum(VATAmount)as TVA,
        count(FiscalNoteId) as NrBon, 
        round(sum(TotalPayment) / count(FiscalNoteId), 2) as ValoareMedieCos, 
        max(InternalTime) as MomentInchidere
    from 
        FiscalNote fn (nolock)
    Join 
        CashLocation cl (nolock) on cl.CashLocationId = fn.CashLocationId
    Join 
        ERPUser u (nolock) on u.UserId = fn.UserId  
    join 
        Site s (nolock) on s.SiteId = fn.SiteId
    where 
        DocumentDate >= @FromDate and DocumentDate <= @ToDate 
        and s.SiteId = @LocId  
        and fn.DocumentStateId = 36
    group by 
        cl.CashLocationName, fn.DocumentDate, OpenCashLocationMovementId, 
        u.UserName
    order by 
        DocumentDate,  CashLocationName, UserName
end
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Is @FromDate (and the other two) local variables or parameters to the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want these variables as arguments, because you don't set them anywhere.  The correct syntax is:

```
Alter Procedure rpt_1 (
    @FromDate Datetime,
    @ToDate Datetime,
    @LocId int
) as
Begin
    select 
        cl.CashLocationName, 
        convert(date,fn.DocumentDate) DocumentDate, 
        u.UserName,
        sum(TotalPayment) TotalVanzare, sum(CashAmount) TotalCash, 
        sum(CardAmount) TotalCard, sum(TicketPaymentAmount) TotalTichete, 
        sum(VATAmount)as TVA,
        count(FiscalNoteId) as NrBon, 
        round(sum(TotalPayment) / count(FiscalNoteId), 2) as ValoareMedieCos, 
        max(InternalTime) as MomentInchidere
    from 
        FiscalNote fn (nolock)
    Join 
        CashLocation cl (nolock) on cl.CashLocationId = fn.CashLocationId
    Join 
        ERPUser u (nolock) on u.UserId = fn.UserId  
    join 
        Site s (nolock) on s.SiteId = fn.SiteId
    where 
        DocumentDate >= @FromDate and DocumentDate <= @ToDate 
        and s.SiteId = @LocId  
        and fn.DocumentStateId = 36
    group by 
        cl.CashLocationName, fn.DocumentDate, OpenCashLocationMovementId, 
        u.UserName
    order by 
        DocumentDate,  CashLocationName, UserName
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the @fromdate and @todate variables without initializing them.Either you should you it as input parameter to the procedure and provide values while calling the procedure or initialize in the procedure.

```
Alter Procedure rpt_1 
@FromDate Datetime,
@ToDate Datetime,
@LocId int

 as
 Begin
    -----

 end
```

OR

```
Alter Procedure rpt_1
as

declare @FromDate Datetime 
declare @ToDate Datetime
declare @LocId int
--initialize here
```